# Calling virtual methods of unknown child class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have the following set up:

```
class Parent {
    virtual void foo(int x) = 0;
};
class Son : public Parent {
    void foo(int x) {};
};
class Daughter : public Parent {
    virtual void foo(int x) {};
};
```

If I have `vector<Parent> parents` and I am going though the vector with a loop as seen here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parents.size(); i++) {
    Parent s = parents[i];
    s.foo(-1);  
}
```

How do I call the children' foos (they could be Sons or Daughters)? I am getting two errors currently:

1. `Variable type 'Parent' is an abstract`
2. `Variable type 'Parent' is an abstract class`

Comment: @Barry fixed the derivation that was just a typo in my question not the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make `Son` and `Daughter` be derived classes of `Parent`:

```
class Son : public Parent {
    ...
};
class Daughter : public Parent {
    ...
};
```

Then, to have a vector of polymorphic objects, you can't store the objects therein. You have to take a vector of pointers to objects for polymorphism to work.

```
vector<Parent*> parents;
```

or better:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Parent>> parents;
```

Why?

- No Parent object can be instantiated because it's an abstract class. You can only create derived classes of it.
- if Parent was not abstract, your code could work, but by putting a Son or a Daughter in the vector, it would be [sliced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: I just left out the : public Parent part. fixing that now.